# What does -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE do?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gnu, bsd

Previously I was receiving warnings from `gcc -std=c99` that `usleep()` was implicitly declared. Then I stumbled across [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053817/2002146), which led me to use `-D_BSD_SOURCE`. However, now `gcc` tells me that `-D_BSD_SOURCE` has been deprecated and I should use `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` instead.

```
#warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
```

Why is `-D_BSD_SOURCE` deprecated? Why is `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` used instead? And what does it do?

I did [some googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20%22-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE%22), and the results are just filled with people using it to shut `gcc` up. I couldn't find out *why* `-D_BSD_SOURCE` has been deprecated, just that it is.

Comment: It happened in [glibc 2.20](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Release/2.20#Deprecation_of__BSD_SOURCE_and__SVID_SOURCE_feature_macros).  As for what it does, the [glibc documentation explains what the intended effect is](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-_005fDEFAULT_005fSOURCE).

Comment: the usleep() function is defined in the header file: unistd.h  however,  per the man page, it is obsoleted,   and to use nanosleep instead.  the function nanosleep() is defined in the header file: time.h  also, the link step. for gcc, needs the '-lrt' parameter

Comment: @user3629249 This [man page for librt](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/3lib/librt/) suggests that `new application development need not specify -lrt`, but yes I have moved to nanosleep() now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) describes each feature test macro (FTM) including `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`:

> If you define this macro, most features are included apart from
>   X/Open, LFS and GNU extensions: the effect is to enable features from
>   the 2008 edition of POSIX, as well as certain BSD and SVID features
>   without a separate feature test macro to control them. Defining this
>   macro, on its own and without using compiler options such as `-ansi` or
>   `-std=c99`, has the same effect as not defining any feature test macros; defining it together with other feature test macros, or when options
>   such as `-ansi` are used, enables those features even when the other
>   options would otherwise cause them to be disabled.

[This LWN.net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/590381/)  about FTMs provides us with a rationale (among other perhaps interesting info):

> The original intent seems to have been that, within each of the glibc
>   header files that employs FTMs, only one of the `__USE_*` internal
>   macros should govern the exposure of any particular definition.
>   Additionally, the macros should not be used in nested `#ifdef`
>   directives. An inspection of the glibc header files quickly shows that
>   the reality is far from the intent, a situation that led Roland
>   McGrath [to suggest](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.glibc.alpha/30489/focus=30767) that it was time for a major cleanup to bring
>   things back to the intended situation. Roland thought that task could
>   be simplified by eliminating the `_BSD_SOURCE` and `_SVID_SOURCE` FTMs,
>   which, although they had a purpose historically, have ceased to be
>   useful these days. Anymore, he said, the only macros that are needed
>   for modern source code are those that relate to formal standards plus
>   `_GNU_SOURCE`.
>
> Joseph Myers [duly obliged](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.glibc.alpha/37721) with a series of patches to implement the
>   first steps in this work. The conservative approach encouraged by
>   Roland meant that the deprecation of the `_BSD_SOURCE` and
>   `_SVID_SOURCE` FTMs is taking place across two glibc versions. Version
>   2.19 of glibc added a new FTM, `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`. Defining this macro causes the default definitions to be exposed even when the explicit
>   definition of other macros would cause that not to happen. The effect
>   of defining this macro is equivalent to the effect of explicitly
>   defining three macros in earlier glibc versions:
>
> ```
> cc -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809C
> ```

So if you need to define `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE`, simply define `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` too. glibc versions <= 2.18 don't care about it and versions >= 2.19 don't warn if both or all three are defined.

Comment: Of course the real fix is to avoid the deprecated `usleep` (if possible) and use [`nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) instead as the Single Unix Specification hasn't removed that.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Yeah, I had written something about that, but he didn't ask about this specific case and so it didn't end up in the answer. And to use `nanosleep()` with `-std=c99`, you also have to define a FTM, but at least it's a POSIX one!

Answer (score 7):

i need portability beyond linux and beyond glibc, and i dislike #ifdef's. so:

```
/* asprintf() does not appear on linux without this */
#define _GNU_SOURCE

/* gettimeofday() does not appear on linux without this. */
#define _BSD_SOURCE

/* modern glibc will complain about the above if it doesn't see this. */
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
```