# After importing unistd.h, compiler states that sbrk() is an implicit declaration. Why is this?

Tags: c, gcc, centos, unistd.h, sbrk

I'm trying to implement `malloc` on CentOS, but I keep getting the error:

```
malloc.c: In function ‘malloc’:
malloc.c:11:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sbrk’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     mem_ptr = sbrk(SIXTY_FOUR_K); /* Allocate 64 kB of memory */
```

Here is the code that the compiler warning is referencing:

```
#include "malloc.h"
#include <unistd.h>

void * malloc(size_t bytes) {
    uintptr_t mem_ptr;

    if (bytes <= 0) { /* If user passes in bad value, return NULL */
        return NULL;
    }

    mem_ptr = sbrk(SIXTY_FOUR_K); /* Allocate 64 kB of memory */

    if (mem_ptr == -1) { /* sbrk() failed */
        return NULL;
    }

    return (void *)mem_ptr;
}
```

According to the documentation on `sbrk`, you should just have to import `unistd.h`, which I do. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also, why are you including the standard malloc.h and then defining your own?

Comment: I'm including my own malloc.h, denoted by the quotes. The standard lib malloc would be denoted by <>

Comment: And @user3386109, I'm on CentOS Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at the Feature Test Macro requirements?

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    brk(), sbrk():
>        Since glibc 2.12:
>            _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE ||
>                (_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
>                    _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED) &&
>                !(_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600)
>        Before glibc 2.12:
>            _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
> ```

See if compiling with something like `-D_SVID_SOURCE` will work (though it looks like there are a number of options based on that macro list)

As of glibc 2.19, a new feature test macro was added, `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` which is meant to replace `_BSD_SOURCE` and `_SVID_SOURCE`.  For more information on `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`, see this question: [What does -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201515/what-does-d-default-source-do)

Comment: And starting with glibc 2.19, it is declared by default (`_DEFAULT_SOURCE`), which may have led to the confusion.

Comment: Using your suggested flag worked like a charm. Thanks so much!