# How not to hog CPU while waiting for some event?

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, c++11

I would like to write some code that wakes up on (or sleep until) some event.

I have a piece of code that sleeps until some event happens, such as when alarmed by a clock.

Pseudo code:

```
int main() {
  TimePoint someTp("3PM");
  std::this_thread::sleep_until(someTP);
}
```

This is my current implementation, but this hogs about 10% of my CPU power. I think my design is flawed, is there any better solution for this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: sleep shouldn't hog CPU - how are you determining it hogs 10% of the CPU?

Comment: A truly sleeping thread should never use any CPU. What are you using to measure CPU usage?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I am using Linux System Monitor. Perhaps this is not accurate?

Comment: Due to the amount of polling and rendering system monitors need to do, they eat up some CPU on their own. You should specifically check the CPU usage of your _process_ rather than the overall system.

Comment: @Sam Miller - TimePoint is like a boost::posix_time object, i.e. HH-MM-SS.

Comment: @Ates Goral - Thanks. You are right. I will do some kind of profiling on the app specifically.

Comment: @will : What kernel version are you running?

Comment: @ildjarn - hi, I'm using Fedora 15, it's 2.6.38 I think.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in the implementation of  `std::this_thread:sleep_until(..)` which calls `sleep_for(..)`, which calls `nanosleep()`.

(See the [gnu sources](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01060_source.html#l00271), line 271.)

See the following Stackoverflow questions:

- [nanosleep high cpu usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125297/nanosleep-high-cpu-usage)  (Linux high-cpu issue calling nanosleep.)
- [boost::this_thread::sleep() vs. nanosleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072912/boostthis-threadsleep-vs-nanosleep)

You don't appear to need the high resolution of `nanosleep()`.  You might write your own solution with a permissive open source license, and call `sleep()` instead of `nanosleep().`

If you do need sub-second resolution, I recommend the technique of calling `select()` rather than `nanosleep()`.  `select()` is designed to block very efficiently for sub-second delays, and the timeout parameter is respected accurately enough by most operating systems that it is useful for sub-second timing while yielding the CPU.

You can even create a socket for the purpose of passing to `select()`, in the`error_fds` parameter, where the socket can be used as a cross-thread "signal" when it is passed to `close()` and becomes an "error" state socket.

Comment: What would switching to a permissive license achieve?

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I use gcc's c++0x std::this_thread::sleep_for actually. I will consider your suggestions.

Comment: @ildjarn -- The same problem has been reported post 2.6.22, so I disagree.

Comment: Ah, the page I was looking at didn't mention that, only the 2.5.39 change. Good to know :-]

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be using an event driven library such as [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) or [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) rather than sleeping for some duration.

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation can be to use a `Semaphore`.

Keep your `worker thread` blocked on a semaphore and signal the `semaphore` from another thread where the alarm clock event occurs.

```
void* workerThread(void*) 
{
     TimePoint someTp("3PM");
     sem_Wait();    //Thread remains blocked here
}

void timercallback()
{
    sem_post(); //Signals worker thread to move ahead

}
```

Comment: +1 [Always prefer a semaphore to a busy wait](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/in-praise-of-idleness/).

Comment: Waiting idle is certainly better than busy waiting (thanks for the link to my blog post), but I'm not sure what a semaphore achieves here. You have a timercallback() which somehow (you don't say how) is called when the time expires. Why not just run your code in the callback? There may be a reason but it isn't described.

That is, in your sample solution the important detail (how to schedule a timercallback) is omitted.

Also, thankfully, the OP never suggested busy waiting.